# how to do image processing like FaceGoo

Tags: iphone, image-processing, image-manipulation

I want to twist a photo like that, just use finger to tap on the screen then slide, anyone has any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

The underlying technology for FaceGoo is OpenGL texture mapping.  The distortions in the face come from manipulation of a mesh whose vertices are mapped to regularly spaced points on the image.  When the points in the mesh are displaced from their original location, the face appears to move because the triangles move.